# Unity container creation slowdown on some machines

Tags: c#, unity-container, performance

On my develop machine all ok, but when I try app on test machine with WinXp sp3 
I encountered a problem.

The method call contains the code below takes 1,5 minute

`var c = new UnityContainer();`

Unity version 2.0.414.0
.Net Framework v 3.5 sp1

Does any one know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: When I build sources of varsion 50871 problem gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your test machine have internet access? If not, it could be hanging trying to verify the authenticode certificate on the binary. A quick test would be to build Unity from source and use that dll instead. If it doesn't hang then that was the problem. There's a way turn off the cert check in the app.config file; I'll update this answer once I get a chance to look it up.

Comment: Thank you very much! To remove this check add <runtime> <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> </runtime> to app.config

Comment: Yep, that was the switch I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will make a different or not, but you can try this instead.

```
UnityContainer c = new UnityContainer();
OR
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
```

Also, have you done the following:

1. Provide an XML format configuration file that adheres to the schema shown in Source Schema for the Unity Application Block.
2. Use the methods of the container to add specific registration entries for default and named mappings.
3. Use the container configuration API to provide a custom configuration for the container.

Maybe this can help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx

Comment: On my dev PC I have configuration that works fine, but when I get this issue I try to cut anything that not case to problem.