# Unity - How to be notified when an object is resolved/instanciated?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I am currently investigating some performance issue in a big application setup with Unity. I am suspecting that we are allocating too many objects. Since Unity handles objects creation/allocation, is there an event or something that I could log when an object is resolved or created by Unity? I'd like a full trace so that I understand better what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of performance issue you have? Once I have this kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399764/unity-container-creation-slowdown-on-some-machines

Answer (score 3):

I would not go for a custom `LifetimeManager`. If you want to know when Unity creates a new object you should get that information directly from Unity's build pipeline.

There is an extension in the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com) which raises events before and after the creation of an object by the container. Have a look at the sources in the *TecX.Unity* project (folder Notification). The tests in *TecX.Unity.Tests* show how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to search in way of custom life time manager. You can wrap default life time manager and log time of object instantiating.
Maybe this link help you: http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Writing-Custom-Lifetime-Managers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can trace the dependency resolution by way of an `UnityContainerExtension`. Build one that adds a single builder strategy at the `TypeMapping` stage:

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.Add(_builderStrategy, UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }
```

Inside the `PreBuildUp` method of the `BuilderStrategy` you can see what is about to be resolved, and inside the `PostBuildUp` method you can see what has been resolved.

Comment: You don't see wether the object is actually constructed if you add your strategy to the `TypeMapping` stage. E.g. a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` would set the `BuilderContext.Existing` property to its cached value. You can't insert a strategy at the front of a `BuildStage` otherwise your strategy should be the very first one in the `Creation` stage. Due to this limitation you have to append your strategy to the `PreCreation` stage.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solition is to add some logging code in he default constructor of the objects you think are being created multiple times and dump the stack trace. You can also set break points in this code and inspect the stack during debugging.

Comment: I though of that one... but there's way too much code to update. :(